# Apache NIFI :: Connection to windows server and execute powershell script

Tags: apache-nifi

I have a requirement to connect to another windows server from NIFI server and execute Powershell script
scheduled on daily basis.

Please help me in knowing the processors which can help me to achieve the same.

Answer (score 3):

you can use `ExecuteProcess` or `ExecuteStreamCommand` to run powershell script.

And inside this powershell script use `Invoke-Command -ComputerName $remoteServer -ScriptBlock ...` to call a remote part of script

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command?view=powershell-7#examples

if your nifi runs on linux or macos - you still have an option to install powershell there: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell-core-on-linux?view=powershell-7